# HtmlPage.Document.QueryString within a UserControl

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, navigation, query-string

A) If I check the querystring within a Navigation Page, things work great.

B) But if I check the querystring within a UserControl (which is delcared in the Navigation Page), the querystring shows it is empty.

Question) If there a way to check for a querystring by the UserControl (i.e. a child control who ultimately has a Navigation Page as a parent)???

Thanks!!

Comment: I found a work-around hack by taking the Uri (from the contentframe_navigatedTo event) and parsing the "?key=value" out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my comment above.